# Fetch max records of parent in one to many relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Suppose two class are there a ParentClass and a ChildClass. Parent is having a bag to have childs.
I have tried .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()) and distinct() which filters out the repeatitions and when fetching .SetMaxResults() I am not getting it in ParentClass level.

Is there anything which can be used to get make the .SetMaxResults() to work on ParentClass level and not on ChildClass. I need to enforce the maxresults in Parent level.

Example ParentClass having 6 childs and setmaxresults(6) and distinct() would result me to a single ParentClass while I am looking for more 5 ParentClass records in my query. And my criteria includes 3 parameters to match with Parent record and 2 to match with Child record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to use the subquery. The documentation [14.11. Subqueries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-subqueries).

It will work like an inner select. The subquery will contain WHERE clause with 2 params to match `Child`, and a projection to return `Parent.ID`. The master query will then contain 3 params to filter `Parent` and also a call to subquery to match the `Parent ID`.

The subquery:

```
var sub = DetachedCriteria
 .For<Child>()
 .Add(Restrictions.In("FirsChildProperty", new int[] {1, 2 })) // WHERE
 .Add(Restrictions.... // Second
 .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Parent.ID")); // Parent ID as a SELECT clause
```

The master query:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Parent>()
 .Add(Restrictions.In("FirsParentProperty", new int[] {1, 2 })) // WHERE
 .Add(Restrictions.... // the second
 .Add(Restrictions.... // the third
 // no filter to match children
 .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", sub)); // Parent.ID in (select
 // now paging just over Parent table....
 .SetFirstResult(100) // skip some rows
 .SetMaxResults(20)   // take 20

var result = criteria.List<Parent>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got a small query over it. It is like my parent first column is "First", second is "Second" and third is "Third" and for child its "Fourth" and "Fifth". I have a list of these 5 inputs with me, if I am using Restrictions.In would it follow the same sequence such as Parent having the 3 and child having 2. Or should I use loop to add restrictions.

Comment: Not sure if I do understand ;) But. Subquery `sub` is working with a child. So you can apply any filter (In, equal, Like) on its properties there. Then when working with parent `criteria` any Restriction could go to Parent properties (FirstName Equals... Age is greater then...) The result will then filter the Parent and Take only parent IDs which meet the Child result in subquery

Comment: It is indeed giving some records but "Param1","Param2,"Param3","Param4","Param5" must strictly match with parents param1,param2,param3 and in child param4,param5.Which is not strictly matching.

Comment: The solution I showed you is pretty flexible. But there must be some other logic put in place. So, you will create the `Subquery` and base on the condition you will add restrictions (later WHERE clause elements). This place you will use to restrict parent on a child properties. The same with `Criteria query`, which can be adjusted to any filter on Parent. Use if, switch... just work with `criteria` and `sub` as needed. Finally put them together and call .List<Parent>()...

Comment: Do we have something which could enforce the setmaxrecords on parent level. Presently it is on child level when building the recordset. And when distinct is being made the recordset once again gets trimmed down.

Comment: Let's think about it as the SQL SELECT Statement. You also have to do paging only on parent table, and filter it with the IN clause and inner select. That's how my suggestion works

Comment: Using detachedcriteria helped me out :) Thank you @Radim

Comment: Great to see that. Good luck with NHibernate ;)